# Send a date to an action in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, datepicker

I have a datepicker and I need to get a date and pass that date to the controller. So far I have the following code:

**JavaScript function:**

```
$(function () {
  intDate = Date; 
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      onClose: function (select_date) {
          //console.log(select_date);
          var date = $('#datepicker').val();
          console.log(date.toString());
          $.ajax('/Home/GetUserInfoDate', {
              data: {
                  intDate: date
              },
              success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  //this will happen on success of request
                  $('#divData').html(data);
              },
              error: function () {
                  console.log("error handler when ajax request fails... ");
              },

          });
          //console.log(date);
      }
  });
});
```

**Model:**

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> getInfoByDate(DateTime date)
    {
      CareDB context = new CareDB();

      SqlParameter Date = new SqlParameter("@Date", date);

      object[] parameters = new object[] { Date };

      IEnumerable<DateTime> lst = context.ReleaseDate.SqlQuery("_UserInformationByDate @Date", parameters).ToList();

      context.Dispose();
      context = null;
      return lst;
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult EmployeeDate(MvcApplication1.Models.DateTime date)
    {
      Models.BL oBL = new Models.BL();

      IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.DateTime> lstEmployees = oBL.getInfoByDate(date);

      ViewBag.DataSource = lstEmployees;

      return View("EmployeeInformation");
    }
```

When I try to execute the function I get this message:

> jquery-1.10.2.js:8706 GET http://localhost:51299/Home/GetUserInfoDate?intDate=05%2F03%2F2016 404 (Not Found)

And then of course say that it was an error.

I think the problem is with the format of the date, because as you can see it has a weird format.. Any ideas?

Any help will be appreciated! thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look like a problem with the date format. 404 means the requested `http://localhost:51299/Home/GetUserInfoDate` location is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are sending request to `GetUserInfoDate` however your controller name is `getInfoByDate` you need to change your code like this:

```
$(function () {
  intDate = Date; 
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      onClose: function (select_date) {
          //console.log(select_date);
          var date = $('#datepicker').val();
          console.log(date.toString());
          $.ajax('/Home/getInfoByDate', {
              data: {
                  date: date
              },
              success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  //this will happen on success of request
                  $('#divData').html(data);
              },
              error: function () {
              console.log("error handler when ajax request fails... ");
          },

          });
          //console.log(date);
          }
  });
```

});